# How can I map a port from Elastic Beanstalk to my Docker container for my Flask app?

Tags: python, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 build-essential python3-pip
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV FLASK_APP application.py
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

So my app runs on port 5000. When I try to deploy to ElasticBeanstalk, how can I specify that it should forward to port 5000?

In my ELB, I have:
[image]

I've seen some answers using `Dockerfile.aws.json`, but I don't think I need that since I won't be publishing my Docker image. Is that right?

In my application logs, I see:

```
 * Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ports are set using [Dockerrun.aws.json v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence).

The `Image` option is **optional** if you have your own `Dockerfile`.

The `Ports` option:

> Lists the ports to expose on the Docker container. Elastic Beanstalk uses the ContainerPort value to connect the Docker container to the **reverse proxy** running on the host.